# how do override Html template magento2?

Tags: magento2, overrides, module, magento2-dev-beta

I create new Block `Xyaddons\Productzoom\Block\Product\View\Gallery` override Block `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery`.
I want set template `image.phtml` in `Xyaddons_Productzoom::product/image.phtml` override template `product/view/base-image.phtml` in core. 
I try create function in block new Block. But i not success. so any help me? thank so much!

```
public function beforeToHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Gallery $originalBlock) {       
        $originalBlock->setTemplate('Xyaddons_Productzoom::produtc/image.phtml');
    }
```

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: it don't run template Xyaddons_Productzoom::produtc/image.phtml

Comment: I'm assuming "produtc" is a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog_product_gallery">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Xyaddons_Productzoom::produtc/image.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your function,
Template path spelling mistake.

```
public function beforeToHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Gallery $originalBlock) {       
        $originalBlock->setTemplate('Xyaddons_Productzoom::produtc/image.phtml');
    }
```

check directory path spelling mistake **produtc/image.phtml** instead of **product/image.phtml.**

Check folder name with product not produtc and try again.

Moreover, you have to define the plugin in the di.xml file of your module

```
<type name="\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Gallery">
    <plugin name="xyaddons-productzoom-product-gallery" type="Xyaddons\Productzoom\Block\Product\View\Gallery" sortOrder="10"/>
</type>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Template path is true. but code don't run to function beforeToHtml().